# Preventing me to build app Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle

here`https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2YUz5ajNLHLc0N6Z2hJUGZMVWc/view?usp=sharing

Preventing me to build app  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzv$zzb.class

I have tried ./gradlew clean but doesn't work , need help !!

Comment: Add your build.gradle file here